# What does leaving a hasher in a dirty state mean in RUST

Tags: rust

I’ve been trying to understand the `SHA256` implementation in RUST. In particular, I have come across the trait `digest::FixedOutputDirty` which according to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.FixedOutputDirty.html#tymethod.finalize_into_dirty) "Usage of this trait in user code is discouraged. Instead use the `FixedOutput::finalize_fixed` or `FixedOutput::finalize_fixed_reset` methods". Why is that? Also, the method `finalize_into_dirty` which the same documentation says should be called once unless `Reset::reset` is called after which `finalize_into_dirty` may be called again and so on... Why should one call `Reset::reset` after each call to `finalize_into_dirty`. In other words, what happens if `Reset::reset` is not called and we call `finalize_into_dirty` multiple times successively?

**EDIT 1:** According to the documentation `finalize_fixed_reset` retrieves the hashing result and resets the hasher instance while `finalize_fixed` retrieves the result and consumes the hasher instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't actually mean anything *in Rust*. It means something *for the digest crate*: `finalize_into_dirty` finalizes the hash (if necessary) then returns the result but leaves the internal buffer in whatever state the finalization put it. This means you can keep adding new data to the hash but it's likely going to be nonsense.

I can't tell you why the `digest` folk thought this was a useful concept, you'd have to ask them. It may have been imagined as an optimisation for hashes where the finalisation step is a no-op, where you could ask for the hash value at "checkpoints" then keep on hashing.

edit: [Issue 180](https://github.com/RustCrypto/traits/pull/180), it is related to an optimisation: apparently implementations previously had to `reset()` the internal buffer even when the digest would be *consumed* (so it couldn't be reused, and resetting was a waste of time). So this is an "under the hood" implementation detail, you *really* should not concern yourself with it.

Comment: Can you also comment on the `reset` part? Thank you!

Comment: There's really nothing to comment about. `reset` resets the digest into its initial state, so that you can reuse it as if it were new but you don't have to reallocate an internal buffer.

Comment: FWIW I edited in the origin of the trait, which somewhat explains the reasoning and purpose. The tldr is that as a *user* of digest you have absolutely no reason to care about it, or touch it in any way. Both traits are part of the underlying implemenation details of digests.

Comment: I thought this may be a sort of vulnerability in case one wants to incorporate this method in e.g., a signature verification algorithm for a file...and I thought if you don't use `reset` + `finalize_into_dirty` you're calculating something you weren't planning on!